# open a file right after saving completes

Tags: c#, silverlight, savefiledialog

I have a silverlight application and I am using the save file dialog popup to save a csv file to the user pc.

I want the csv file to open up (in his excel\notepad or whatever) immediately after I finish writing the file to the stream I get from OpenFile().

Is this possible?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the SaveFileDialog. On the desktop, this would be solved using the `System.Diagnostics.Process` class. Assuming a file associated already exists for the extension .csv, and `ProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute` is set to `true`, specifying the file as the target to run will load the appropriate program with the file. I don't know what the Silverlight equivalent is, and it may not exist (the entire System.Diagnostics namespace seems to be missing from Silverlight), but that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way you can do this is if the application has been granted elevated trust.  Typically that means the application needs to be running in Out-of-Browser mode.  If that's an option for you, Microsoft has a pretty handy how-to: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721082(v=vs.95).aspx